# standard output stream of void method.invoke()

Tags: java, methods, reflection, invoke

How can I get the standard output stream of a void method that I invoked as a string?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
if(method.getGenericReturnType().toString().equals("void"))
       method.invoke(instance, param);
else{
       Object obj = method.invoke(instance, param);
       System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

If i try to do the same to a void method, i get a null exception.

Comment: What do you mean by _standard output stream of a void method_?

Comment: if the method has a System.out.println() call in it, I need to be able to get the String of what the function is printing

Comment: Why do you think that what you are attempting with reflection will achieve that? How is this piece of code related to that goal?

Comment: I need to compile and run a class on a server and after that get the results to the client. Is there any other approach?

Comment: thanks for the redirect trick. it worked!